# WCF WebSite not returning JSON (Whereas WCF Service Application does)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

I have used VS2012 to create a WCF WebSite (Add->New Web Site-> WCF Service).  I want to get the web site to return JSON-formatted data.

I edited the Service.cs and IService.cs classes, and edited the web.config to look as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "one", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string One();


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "two", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Two();


}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

public class Service : IService
{
    public string One()
    {
        return "{\"Result\":\"One\"}";
    }

    public string Two()
    {
        return "{\"Result\":\"Two\"}";
    }



}


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ZuantResearchWCFServiceWebSite.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour" bindingConfiguration="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ZuantResearchWCFServiceWebSite.IService" ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehaviour">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>


    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The Service.svc file contains one line:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>
```

Going to the browser, I then tap in either of the following URIs:

```
http://localhost:54795/Service.svc/one
http://localhost:54795/Service.svc/two
```

In each case I get a completely blank page.

Why isn't my website returning any JSON?

I have created a WCF Service Application with exactly the same services and configuration etc and this does return the JSON correctly to the browser.

Can anyone explain the key differences between configuring a WCF Service WebSite and a WCF Service Application, and tell me why the application returns the JSON but the website does not?

Thanks very much.

Comment: When you hit the URL and you are taken to a blank page does the page give you the option to save a file at the bottom?

Comment: It is just an entirely blank page.